# Flutter/Dart :How to add validation to radio button like TextFormField?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

How can I add validation to Radio Button in Flutter? I know there's a package called [flutter_form_builder](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_builder) but I don't want to use it. Is there any way to add validation to the radio button? I would like it to validate it using formkey and I can't post code because the whole form is dynamic and I don't have permission to post the code online so any help is appreciated. Can I make a custom radio button?

Comment: What do you mean by "validate"? A RadioButton is by definition valid. it has exactly two states, on and off, if one of those states were invalid, you would not need a radiobutton.

Comment: This answer has helped me alot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61368025/flutter-validate-radio-buttons.

Comment: @UTKARSHSharma I can't because fields are dynamic otherwise it's easy.

Comment: @nvoigt validate means to check like TextFormField to see if user has selected a value. By default, in our app we can't give user a default value, that's why validation is needed.

Comment: @FarrukhSajjad thanks but as I already said in the question I don't want to use that plugin.

Comment: So I assume you mean you want to validate a radio button **group** to see if one is selected. What is keeping you? Assuming you need the value anyway and know how to find out which is selected, what kind of validation are you looking for?

Comment: @nvoigt I don't need the value of every radio button, only which are required.

Answer (score 8):

I know it is a bit late. Just use FormBuilder, for [example](https://medium.com/saugo360/creating-custom-form-fields-in-flutter-85a8f46c2f41).

or if you use it inside Form(), this is an example:

```
FormField(
                builder: (FormFieldState<bool> state) {
                  return Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text('Where is occurrence happened?'),
                          state.hasError
                              ? Text(
                                  state.errorText,
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                                )
                              : Container(),
                          RadioListTile(
                            ...
                            onChanged: (SomeValueType value) {
                              ...                              
                              state.setValue(true);
                            },
                          ),
                          RadioListTile(
                            ...
                          ),
                        ],
                      ));
                },
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value != true) {
                    return 'Please choose location';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              )
```

in that code, the validator will run when you call FormState.validate(), and then show the  ErrorText.